# Spring Data Reactive Mongo Operator how to call unset operation on nested field after performing lookup stage in an aggregate pipleine

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-mongodb-reactive

I am merging records from two collections `projects` and `card_types` in an aggregation pipeline and then trying to remove the `cardFields` field of the merged record from the result. So the idea is that from the aggregate result which will be

```
{
   "projectId": "foo",
   ...
   "cardTypes": [
     {
        "itemId": "bar",
        "itemType": "Defect",
        "cardFields": [ { ... more objects here ...} ]
     },
     {
        ... more card types ...
     }
   ],
}
```

into

```
{
   "projectId": "foo",
   ...
   "cardTypes": [
     {
        "itemId": "bar",
        "itemType": "Defect"
        ...
     },
     {
        ... more card types ...
     }
   ],
}
```

The method I wrote is

```
public Flux<Document> getProjectDetails(String enterpriseId, String projectId) {
    AggregationOperation unset = UnsetOperation.unset("cardTypes.cardFields");
    return mongoOperations.aggregate(
            Aggregation.newAggregation(match(where(accountIdKeyName).is(enterpriseId).and(ownerIdKeyName).is(projectId)),
                    lookup("card_types", accountIdKeyName, accountIdKeyName, "cardTypes"),
                    unset), "project", Document.class);
}
```

The method fails with exception

`org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Command failed with error 40324 (Location40324): 'Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$unset''`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the method implementation to use `$project` instead

```
public Flux<Document> getProjectDetails(String enterpriseId, String projectId) {
    List<AggregationOperation> pipeline = new ArrayList<>();
    pipeline.add(match(where(accountIdKeyName).is(enterpriseId).and(itemIdKeyName).is(projectId)));
    pipeline.add(context ->
            new Document("$lookup", new Document("from", "card_types")
                    .append("localField", "itemId")
                    .append("foreignField", "projectData.boardId")
                    .append("as", "cardTypes")
            ));
    pipeline.add(context ->
            new Document("$lookup", new Document("from", "swim_lanes")
                    .append("localField", "itemId")
                    .append("foreignField", "ownerId")
                    .append("as", "swimLanes")
            ));
    pipeline.add(context -> new Document("$project", new Document("_id", 0).append("cardTypes._id", 0)
            .append("cardTypes.cardFields", 0).append("swimLanes._id", 0)));
    return mongoOperations.aggregate(newAggregation(pipeline), "project", Document.class);
}
```